# MySQL timediff returning unexpected results

Tags: mysql, database

Please consider the following query:

```
SELECT submitted_time FROM jobs WHERE timediff(NOW(), submitted_time) < '24:00:00'
```

My hope is for this to return all rows that have a "submitted_time" column containing a timestamp that was within the last 24 hours, However I am receiving the following results:

```
2017-01-18 14:58:34
2017-01-16 14:58:34
```

If I run the query `SELECT NOW()` I get `2017-01-25 18:58:32`

Which appears to be correct.

What is stranger still is that I have more recent rows in the DB such as:

```
2017-01-24 15:17:13
```

Which are **not** being returned.

I hope I have made a glaringly obvious error that someone can point out, rather than beginning the descent into madness.

Comment: You can compare datetime and timestamp values directly.  There is no reason to be doing timediff in this way.   Within the last 24 hours would simply involve a between query and the use of DATE_ADD.  See this:  http://www.gizmola.com/blog/archives/51-Exploring-Mysql-CURDATE-and-NOW.-The-same-but-different..html

Comment: Thanks very much for the link I shall take a look now and see if I can adapt my query, unfortunately MySql is not my strong suit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be clear, the simplest and probably most performant way to handle this is (as per the link I provided in the comment)

```
SELECT submitted_time FROM jobs WHERE submitted_time > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 DAY);
```

This should be all jobs submitted literally within the last 24 hours at the moment the query is issued.

This might not be important to you for this query, but whenever you apply functions to columns in your table, any indexes you might have can not be used, because the database must run the function(s) on each value in the table before it can perform a comparison.

Using this method you figure out what the comparable datetime needs to be and mysql will use an index on submitted_time for the comparison, assuming that column is indexed appropriately.

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you very much. I will of course award you the correct answer, however I am going to hold off for a couple of days to see if the question draws anyone to come up with exactly why my query didn't work, for posterity.

Comment: The problem with your original attempt is in the comparison.  Timediff returns a "time" value.   '24:00:00' is a string, not a time value.  In order to do the comparison you'd have to CAST the string to a time value using:  CAST('24:00:00' AS time).  Of course this is very confusing and has the issue I mentioned of not using indexes.